# AlertDialog Button does not exist

Tags: android, android-dialog

Suddenly (without any changes in this project code) I started to obtained an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<package>}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Button does not exist
```

that error points to a method which wasn't yet called.

```
private void dialog(String title, String content){
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(content);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialog.setButton(1, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss();
               }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I tried to copy and use that code in other project - same result, and it was working not long ago (same target API etc.). Any idea what I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't hardcode `1` in [`setButton(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29).  Use the constants found in the [`DialogInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html) class to specify which button:

[`DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_NEGATIVE)

[`DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_POSITIVE)

[`DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_NEUTRAL)

Comment: How could one know this?

Answer (score 4):

Change this line:

```
alertDialog.setButton(1, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

To one of these:

```
alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

You can look at the Android Documentation on the [DialogInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html) and on the [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setButton%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) to look at the `setButton` methods.

You could also replace `BUTTON_POSITIVE`, `BUTTON_NEGATIVE`, and `BUTTON_NEUTRAL` with their constant values: `-1`, `-2`, and `-3`, respectively.

So for example:

```
// positive button
alertDialog.setButton(-1, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```